# Validate field only if it contains numeric content jquery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a field in which i can type either email or mobile number but i want to fire this NumValidation validation method only if i enter numeric values in text field right now it is being fired on both cases if i enter numeric value or email.

> Note : Required will be run in both cases

Please suggest any solution.

```
        $.validator.addMethod(
            "NumValidation",
            function (e, a) {
                return ph_no.isValidNumber();
            },
            "Invalid Number"
        ),

    rules: {
  email: { required: !0, NumValidation:!0 },
```

Comment: Better UX to allow user to type either or both

Comment: @mplungjan: My requirement is to give user an option to select only one from both

Comment: Don't use 2 validators (number/email), instead have a single, custom "EmailOrNumber" validator - if it's not a valid number, then check if it's a valid email (in your custom validator)

Comment: Makes no sense.  Validation rules fire on whatever content is entered into the field.  For example, you cannot have one rule for letters and another rule for numbers without first evaluating if numbers or letters are being input.  It's like you want a validation rule that fires before the actual validation rules... impossible without first entering some content.  I think you need to re-evaluate the whole approach.